# sveltekit - How to create global variables per request during SSR

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I need some way to set globals while a request is being server rendered, within .svelte files, not load functions.

The point is to have a way to call something like `setPageTitle('my title')` from any route and have the last component in the markup be `<SEO />` or something similar where it can apply the last `title` that was set via the call in a route.
Could also be `allowIndexing()` or `setPageType('article')`.

Here's what I tried
`SEO.svelte`

```html
<script context="module">
   let title = '';
   export const setPageTitle = (t) => title = t; 
</script>

<script>
    const props = {
        title,
        ...more
    }
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>{props.title}</title>
</svelte:head>
```

Inside `someroute.svelte`

```
<script>
    import { setPageTitle } from '$lib/SEO.svelte';

    setPageTitle('This is some route');
</script>
```

Now this seemed great, and it worked great, until I realized it only works on the first request. Then the data is stale and the module section doesn't run per request.
$page store is good, but it's one way, and locals are only available in load functions and hooks. Also I'm aware that `title` is not reactive, and it won't update the title during client side navigation, but I'm really only looking at the response from the server across requests.

Comment: Why not use a component (or `<svelte:head><title>...` directly)?

Comment: Hey H.B. :)
Yeah that would be perfectly fine for just title, but there's a lot of stuff happening in the SEO.svelte file, and it all depends on different bits of data cross the routes. So this component is used in the root layout once, and the routes call updaters to set different  metas and then since the SEO component is last in the markup, it applies whatever were the final values, then the server returns that.

Comment: Here's the new idea, I just need to figure out an elegant way to implement it.
I have a component that gets imported at the root, it sets an seo context that is a class/object with updater methods, the updaters get the seo context and update it when called. Then in the actual SEO.svelte, it gets the seo context (finalized at this point) and applies it to the svelte:head and schemaorg + og metas. The values assigned by the updaters can be stores themselves, so they can be reactive when on the client side too.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily fix this by making `title` a store in the context module and combine it with `browser` and `$page.data` (altough I wonder why you cannot use the page store in the first place, the title should be available in the load function and it also runs during client navigation).

```html
<script context="module">
   import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
   let title = writable('');
   export const setPageTitle = (t) => title.set(t); 
</script>

<script>
  <!-- no need for anything here, you can access the store directly in your markup -->
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>{browser ? $title : $page.data.title}</title>
</svelte:head>
```

Comment: This is very dangerous, the store will be shared across all requests and users during SSR.
I wish stores were less footgun-y on the server side, but yeah right now I think the only solution is to create a context wrapper.

Comment: I am aware of the shared state, but you can go around that by only using the store if you are in the browser, also do not forget the store will never update from the client to the server. Pretty sure that it will be fine in your case

Comment: This is SEO stuff, it can't be on the client side. The response from the server has to contain the correct page title and other metas, as I said "while a request is being server rendered". I really appreciate the input still, I just need it to work on the server specifically.

Comment: But, wouldn't you get the title as part of the load function for each page anyway ? What exactly is stopping you from using `$page.data.title` ?

Comment: The title isn't coming from load functions, but if I did do that I couldn't build it using the combined route data. It would need to have all the context it needs at the root, unless I put the function in every single +page.js to handle specific cases. I need to have all of the load functions to have returned with their data to be able to generate these metas correctly. Title is the simplest to describe, so that's what I did, but there's about a hundred, and they're kind of a web.